# rigging precision SR5

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, sr5-matrix

If I jumped into a vehicle. Can I drive while the auto-pilot uses the weapons mounted on the vehicle? Or vice versa?

Second, how can a drone use AutoSoft Electronic Warfare? Can it act as Jammer with a roll like the Cyberdeck (Electronic Warfare + Logic [Attack] p. 240) even though he did not have  the attack attribute?  Or can it reduce the noise with a Complex Action and make an Electronic Warfare + Logic [Data Processing] test like p. 268?

Answer (score 2):

pg202, **Change Linked Device Mode**

> A driver who is rigging the vehicle or has a direct neural link to it may activate or deactivate various systems such as sensors, ECM, weapons, and so on as a Free Action. The driver may also call up a status report to monitor the position, heading and speed, damage report, and/or current orders of the vehicle. Activated sensors, ECM, and ECCM systems come
>   online at the start of the next Action Phase, even if the character who activated the system does not have any actions due to their Initiative Score being 0 or less.

Also, I *strongly* suggest you look at the section starting on pg266, the section entitled **Rigging and You** where it details how it works to pilot a vehicle as a Rigger.  The pages that describe these actions are a bit much to copy/paste into an answer but to put a direct response to your request: you turn the vehicle into part of your PAN and you control things fairly simultaneously through the Rigger Control Console (RCC).

The next section after this, starting on pg269 for **Drones** which describes using the AIs for all purposes and including piloting vehicles (most specifically Pilot Softs) and Autosofts for using weapons and even Electronic Warfare. On the page you reference, they reference even one time further to pg441, where they detail *jammer devices* which does not require a noise, it just needs to have a device rating because it creates noise.  You can have an autosoft that works with reducing noise as well as long as you have the resources available.

If you elaborate on your question I will be glad to alter my answer.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, the answer would be no.  When jumped into a machine that you are rigging through DNI, you are now the machine.  You have access to all of it's systems and must deal with them all personally.  The vehicle in question is now your body.  You are able to arm weapons, check readouts, and operate the forward motion of the vehicle the same way as you are able to load a handgun, look at your own body, and walk forward.  Because of this, you still need to divide your time between driving and firing a weapon.  Granted, it's much easier while you're rigged in, simply because you get a ton more passes to do everything then you would out in your meat body (assuming you don't have other reaction enhancers).

For your second question, I would take CatLord's device to check how the autosofts work with your drones.  Those pages he lists should be enough for you to get what you need.

Comment: I put that a rigger can pilot while a 'Soft shoots and vice-versa since the Rigger can, while jacked in, control the vehicle and if using a PAN can in theory use all systems solo (assuming I read the rules right)

Comment: For me, it all depends on if the gun turret is a different device then the car.  If it is, I would expect that you could autopilot it just fine.  Otherwise, it's the same as saying "I'm going to have an autosoft control my feet and run while I use my arms".  It's all one system, so it all is controlled by one source: your brain.